# What's an up-to-date method of getting S-OFF on a HTC One S?

Tags: htc-one-s, s-off

All the instructions I can find for getting S-OFF on a HTC One S seem to be out-of-date.

- [These instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155135) ask you to download soffbin3.zip but the link [takes you to website which thinks it's streaming you a video](http://d-h.st/WrZ) and the [mirror link is dead](http://goo.im/devs/dsb9938/soff/soffbin3.zip)
- [Rumrunner is available](http://rumrunner.us/downloads-2/) but soju.exe frezzes on "please wait"
- [firewater redirects to Sunshine](http://theroot.ninja/) which is a paid service. The Wayback Machine [has a copy of the executable](https://web.archive.org/web/20140519064907/http://firewater-soff.com/firewaterdownload-3) but when I copy the executable to my device and run it, it just... deletes itself.

I'm out of ideas. How do I get S-OFF on my HTC One S in this day and age?

(The only reason I want S-OFF is to install HBOOT 2.16.)

Comment: Pretty sure it's just Rumrunner - I used it to S-OFF my Evo 4G LTE on its highest version possible back when I owned it. Get your fastboot drivers sorted out.

Comment: Use Sunshine and pay the $25... I know it seems stupid to pay, but it works and there isn't any other way to do most HTCs anymore, all the devs that really knew how to do it work on the sunshine product now.

Answer (score 0):

I had: hbot 2.15, s-on, twrp 3.x cm12.

I tried:

- moonshine = told me to read
- rumrunner = told me to stop it on the 1st swig
- sunshine = I am a cheapskate, so no
- fre-something-can't-remember_with_soff.bin = couldn't get the bin and it needed super-cid and was just a bit too much of "could go wrong"

What worked for me:

1. Flashed MagioRom_ONE_S_RC6.zip
2. Flashed the boot.img from that zip
3. booted the rom and disabled screen lock and fastboot
4. enabled dev/adb debug
5. let rumrunner do its work

Could be that rumrunner stalled for you because your phone asked for permission for the adb-connection.
I had to flash the MagioRom because rumrunner seems to prefer a sense rom and cm12 was a bit to far along.